# How to limit the times a script can be run to some time on a particular ip address

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, increment

Im incrementing some value of how many a song is being played whenever a script that selects the song from table is run, but i would like to only increment once within lets say maybe 5 hours. So meaning a user will play a song and it will be counted as a play only the first time and then waits for 5 hours before allowing another increment.

**PHP**

I just have no idea how to do this.

```
$_SESSION['play_id'] = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $_SESSION['play_time'] = time();
    $then = $_SESSION['play_time'];
    $now  = time();
    $diff = $now->diff($then);
    if ($diff > 2 * 1000){
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE music SET plays = plays + 1  WHERE sid = '$id'") or die (mysql_error());
    } else {
        echo 'not yet';
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: `REMOTE_ADDR` is not a reliable way of identifying users. IP addresses change.

Comment: ...and users behind proxies/NAT share addresses.  @SverriM.Olsen

Comment: Can you use the user account instead of the IP address? It's an easy way to ensure that you're targeting the right user and not somebody with the same IP address.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ip = 0
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

> Security issue
>   elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
>           $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
>       }

```
$_SESSION['play_id'] = $ip;
        $_SESSION['play_time'] = time();
        $then = $_SESSION['play_time'];
        $now  = time();
        $diff = $now->diff($then);
        if ($diff > 2 * 1000){
        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE music SET plays = plays + 1  WHERE sid = '$id'") or die (mysql_error());
        } else {
            echo 'not yet';
            }
```

Comment: -1 `HTTP_CLIENT_IP` and `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` can be spoofed, or even used for the huge SQL injection hole the OP has. `0' or '1'='1`

Comment: she on the weekends ;p

Comment: @LozCherone i will check you on weekends

Answer (score 0):

Session could expire before 5 hours while cookies last as long as you set it. Some thoughts here is to set a unique cookie corresponding to the id of each music being played. Let the content be the epoch i.e date('U') time. When a user is about to play the music, just check if the cookie exists, and if it does, if the time difference is still within an hour. If not, make your update. That's all